# Raspberry pi has static IP address

Tags: linux, ip, ip-address, raspberry-pi2

Hi my raspberry pi has got static ip address.Even when its connected to router instead of  192.168.0.*  as it ip address,it is showing 10.21.113.60.
I have tried changing /etc/network/interfaces file

My /etc/network/interfaces file

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

When I looked into raspberry pi login screen i'm able to see two ip address.But ssh only works with 10.21.113.60

Someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

We should get lots of responses (the laptop is responding the Raspberry Pi through the network cable)!  Ctrl+C to stop that.  (If you didn’t then double check your connections and the IP addresses you are using).

As mentioned before, the new IP address will be lost when we reboot, so we need to ensure it is set every time we boot (or at least every time we want it to be when we boot).

To do that we can edit the “cmdline.txt” file which is located on the boot partition of the SD Card.

Make a copy of the file, with the following command:

```
sudo cp /boot/cmdline.txt /boot/cmdline.normal
```

Next edit the original file using nano:

```
sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt
```

At the end of the long line, add the following (you will need to add a space between the last item and “ip”:

ip=192.168.0.x, for x your number

Ctrl+x and y to save and exit.

Make a copy of this file too:

```
sudo cp /boot/cmdline.txt /boot/cmdline.direct
```

You can now reboot the Raspberry Pi (sudo reboot), and next time the IP address will be automatically set.
To change between configurations, simply use the following commands (just remember to edit  /boot/cmdline.direct if you need to change the IP address in future).

sudo cp /boot/cmdline.normal /boot/cmdline.txt
sudo cp /boot/cmdline.direct /boot/cmdline.txt

go to this instructions:
https://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/

Comment: Thanks,I accidentally  setup a static ip in cmdline.txt .Now i removed it and everything starts working fine.